# Get-PnPAzureADUser : Code: BadRequest Message: Invalid filter clause

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I want to filter the Active Directory using email address which is enabled, so i tried this, but i got the below error :-

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $HRUser = Get-PnPAzureADUser -Filter  {AccountEnabled eq "True" and Mail eq test@test.com }
Get-PnPAzureADUser : Code: BadRequest
Message: Invalid filter clause
Inner error:
        AdditionalData:
        date: 2022-12-20T23:54:51
        request-id: 2bd6308e-3afd-46e4-afcf-2898883852a0
        client-request-id: 2bd6308e-3afd-46e4-afcf-2898883852a0
ClientRequestId: 2bd6308e-3afd-46e4-afcf-2898883852a0
At line:1 char:11
+ $HRUser = Get-PnPAzureADUser -Filter  {AccountEnabled eq "True" and M ...
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-PnPAzureADUser], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,PnP.PowerShell.Commands.Principals.GetAzureADUser
```

any advice how i can filter using email and AccountEnabled ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

When I ran the same command as you, I got **same error** as below:

```
Get-PnPAzureADUser -Filter  {AccountEnabled eq "True" and Mail eq admin@xxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com }
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **resolve** the error, I modified the command and got results successfully like below:

```
Get-PnPAzureADUser -Filter  { AccountEnabled eq true and Mail eq 'admin@xxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com'}
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: ok thanks worked perfectly so i need to change `"True"` to `true` + surround  the email with `''`??